# How left join in select union in linq c#?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a problem with this query, I need to get all the results of the master tables mod_solicitud (x), ren_solicitud (y), these tables are related to other tables but not all records of the master tables exist in the related tables, so the applying an inner join, some data is lost, how can I apply a left join in linq to obtain these data or some other technique that allows to obtain all data tables?

example:

```
master tables:
table x,
table y

table a,
table b
```

```
var resultado =
    ((from x in "table x"
        join a in "table a" on a.id equals x.id
        select new
        {
            a.id,
            a.name,
            x.pp
        }).union(from y in "table y"
                join b in "table b" on b.id equals y.id
                select new
                {
                    b.id,
                    b.name,
                    x.ww
                })
    );
```

Comment: Format your code properly or no one will even look at it.

Comment: And is the question "teach me to left join", or "fix that monstrosity for me"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [LEFT OUTER JOIN in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq)

Comment: You should use a MUCH simpler example for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Left Outer Join sample.

```
var sample= (from e in table1
             join d in table2 on e.column equals d.column into ej
             from d in ej.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new {e.column , e.column , d.column });
```

Comment: thanks, i tried this sample in my code and it's works fine,  best regards.